# dojox.Calendar and JsonRest: column view doesn't show events

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to work with dojox.Calendar to show events queried from
a REST server, using a dojo.store.JsonRest (without an Observable store 'cause
events are read-only).

I set initial "dateInterval" mode to "month" so to have "matrix view" displayed
and i intercept "timeIntervalChange" event to change the "query" used by calendar store
to get events on demand when user move between months.

Everythig works well, but if i try to switch from "matrix view" to "column view" (thru calendar navigation buttons) no event is shown even if i see (from firebug console) "timeIntervalChange" events firing and REST store queries regularly submitted to server.

Here is the dojox.Calendar code snippet from my page:

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/date/stamp", "dojo/date/locale", "dijit/Dialog", "dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojox/calendar/Calendar"],
  function(parser, ready, xhr, stamp, locale, Dialog, JsonRest, Calendar) {
    ready(function(){
      var calendarDate = 'the initial ISO date from an MVC model object';
      var query = "";
      var eventStore  = new JsonRest({target: 'the REST service URL'});

      calendar = new Calendar({
                   date: calendarDate,
                   dateInterval: "month",
                   startTimeAttr: "dataOraInizioISO",
                   endTimeAttr: "dataOraFineISO",
                   summaryAttr: "descrizione",
                   decodeDate: function(s){return stamp.fromISOString(s);},
                   encodeDate: function(d){return stamp.toISOString(d);},                   
                   style: "position:relative;width:950px;height:700px",
                   columnViewProps:{minHours:5, maxHours:23, hourSize:40, timeSlotDuration:30},
                   editable: false,
                   selectionMode: "none",
                }, "calendarioIncontri");

      calendar.on("timeIntervalChange", function(e){
          var sStartDate =            
              locale.format(e.startTime,{selector: "date", pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy", fullYear: true});
          var sEndDate =              
              locale.format(e.endTime,{selector: "date", pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy", fullYear: true});

          query = "?" + "dataInizio=" + sStartDate + "&" + "dataFine=" + sEndDate;

          calendar.set('query', query);
          calendar.set('store', eventStore);
      });
```

Note that in order to avoid initial bulk query of all events (!), i set calendar
"store" and "query" properties ONLY when "timeIntervalChange" event fires and 
also note that, as far as i have tested, i NEED to set the calendar "store" property
every time to let new events be shown on matrix view refresh.

But i'm still not able to get events appear on column view!
Any hints?

Many thanks in advance
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

For the record (this question was answered on the Dojo mailing list), this user was trying to show punctual events (events that are starting and ending at the time) which are not supported by the dojox.calendar. If someone is interested by this feature, please add a feature wish to the project on GitHub: https://github.com/damiengarbarino/dojo-calendar